# How to call Cms Block content and html in controller file back end magento2

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm Working with  `magneto 2.` I want to get cms block content  in my custom module controller file.

I want to know to Get the my custom module controller file. i'm not able to do.
i have used code

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();
```

**inside  my controller but  code is not working.
How can I do?**

Comment: Can you post content of your controller file?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
but we have big amount of content
it is not possible with post content .
because i want  generate PDF for perticuler cms block data
and my content is big.
do you have another solution ?
or by post content how it is  possible.
can you please let me know about that.

Answer (score 1):

Try with below block code.

```
echo $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Bl‌​ock')->setBlockId('y‌​our_block_id')->toHt‌​ml();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I have used your given  above code but getting notice error. error is "Notice: Undefined variable: block in"
i got solution and now i am able to do work
now it is working with 
 $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('your_block_id')->toHtml();